# Preview differs from actual screen

Tags: java, netbeans, windows-xp, screen

I have a code that simply creates a screen with some checkboxes and comboboxes. The weird thing is that my preview looks totally different than the real screen when I run the app. The real screen shows littler textfields and comboboxes. How do I get the preview-looks on the real screen?

As you can see at the picture below, the first date-comboboxes are way smaller than the ones below.

[image: Screensoht]

Comment: code in what? browser?

Comment: Nah I code in netbeans. I use the GUI-builder.

Comment: that'd be something helpful to mention in your question, even as just a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it could be a Look and Feel change. I believe by default Netbeans uses Nimbus. When in the GUI Builder, along the top next to the run button you should see a drop-down menu. From there, you can select the default look and feel. You would probably have to change your look and feel for your program, if it already isn't implemented in the code.